# How to run some code before page is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have trouble running some code before page loads in jquery or js. Anything I do the page would have a brief load then my codes run. I run code before user sees the page but it loads in a brief milliseconds then my code runs.

I have done some solutions and didn't do what I want:

- I've put my codes before `document.ready`
- I've put my code in head section
- I've put my code in a function then called the function in head tag
- I also tried `onload()` in js

But the same result: my code runs after milliseconds and user sees the page before running code in these milliseconds

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Most of the approaches you suggest are explicitly designed to **wait** for the page to render before running the code. Some of them should work … depending on what the code actually does … which we don't know. Why it **matters** that the code runs before the page renders is unclear.

Comment: @sanjundev — That makes no sense at all. You can't fire a blur event on a control before the control exists … which happens when the page renders … which defeats the object of running the code before the page renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with body hidden and show it after your code is executed.

```
<html>
...
<body style='display:none'>
  ...
  <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
       ...
       $(document.body).show();
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts inside the `<head>` will run before this occurs, but there won't be access to the elements on the page.
Try this code

```
   <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("After click ok you'll see the page content!!!");
    </script>
    rest of the page
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your code in 'loading' state of document via `document.readyState` but in this state DOM is not ready to operate. Here your have example how to use `document.readyState` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#Different_states_of_readiness What actualy do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't but anycode in `<head>`
My suggestion is to use loader, so make the body tag invisible using css `display:none`
so your code will be run as if the page isn't loaded yet.
then you add `$(document).ready({$('body').css('display','block')})`

Answer (score -2):

Jquery and Javascript are client side languages, and are read by the browser as the page loads.

Usually we would use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

This is to make sure the elements are loaded on screen before the JS functions run to make sure any elements that are needed for the script have been loaded.

What you seem to be doing is running the script at the same time as the page loads so there might be something in the script that prevents the rest of the HTML from loading as this is running and thats why you see the load time.

You should look at PHP. (hypertext pre-processor) This is a server side language rather than client side. So it pre-processes what you want server side and then sends that to the users client/browser.

Check out http://www.developphp.com/